# Xamarin addin works only for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: installation

I downloaded the Xamarin add-in to my Visual Studio 2013, and now my VS is trashed, because it appears to work ONLY with VS 2015. Isn't there a VS 2013 version?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually complete the installation because I noticed that it keeps wanting to install VS 2015 Community Edition and add Xamarin to that rather than add it to my existing VS 2013 installation.  I haven't found an answer yet searching the web, but if I find one, I'll post here.